# What was the out-of-universe purpose of Tom Bombadil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tom-bombadil

While reading [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1589/120088) on who/what Tom Bombadil was, I started wondering what Tolkien's intention for him was and why he was created the way he was? So, specifically

- What did Tom represent?
- Why was the character written the way he was?
- Why was he included in the story?
- What was his purpose in Tolkien's mind?

So, it's not about his purpose in the book and how he helps the plot (or not, which is answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71895/120088)) but why Tolkien included him anyway.

Comment: Similar question on Literature SE: [What is Tom Bombadil's importance in The Lord of the Rings?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12103/17)

Comment: It is unclear to me how this isn’t a duplicate of the question titled “Who or what was Tom Bombadil?”. In fact this very question is [answered there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46928) by one of the best Tolkien experts this site has had. And covers the points made by Rand below. I will withhold my vote for now only because it is binding.

Comment: Basically a dupe of [Who or what was Tom Bombadil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/who-or-what-was-tom-bombadil). Note that the other question has answers that also cover his out-of-universe origin and reason for inclusion.

Comment: While I can understand the argument of duplication, I think this actually asks for JRRT's motives, rather than any kind of in-world description or deduction. Most of the responses in the linked query involve "this is what Tom seems to be" / "this is what Tom clearly isn't".

Comment: @elemtilas, the question never limits it to being in-universe. The fact that the answers were is beside the point. The question both allows for out-of-universe answers and has an out-of-universe answer. I can't see your argument.

Comment: @Edlothiad -- I'd argue that the limitation is implicit, in the title question, *Who or What is T.B.* where the focus is clearly on T.B. as a character, or person, within Middle Earth, & also in the question body.  The OP further restricts by offering things for the respondent to consider: *Was he an elf...of wizardly stock...something else*.  OP never broadens the query by asking what JRRT thought or said. The present query very clearly focuses on the "out-of-universe purpose" and very clearly asks us to consider JRRT's perspective, not the in world perspective. Related, but not identical.

Comment: @elemtilas, I think this is dependent on how one reads the title. Given the age of the question and the context of when the question was asked I think it is implied that this be a very generic cover-all question. Further, it is policy on meta to close specific questions to the more general. As such this being clearly focused and specific only furthers the reason for duping.

Comment: @Edlothiad -- Fair enough. I tend to read titles fairly straightforward. Sometimes I'm wrong, like when an OP asks a completely different question in the body, or adds all kinds of qualifiers to title. I don't think the age of a question really changes the meaning of the question, though. I certainly won't argue policy, except to note that very many questions here are quite specific, and that I don't think either question is overly broad nor overly specific. They simply ask different things about the same person. E.g., in history: who was Gen. MacArthur asks about the person ...

Comment: (cont) ... while why did the president send him to the Pacific theatre asks about external motivation. They touch on the same topic, but are very different in scope & focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tolkien said that Bombadil represented a sort of passive pacifism, which was important to represent in the story but couldn't play much of a role in the actual plot.**

From Tolkien's Letters, letter #144:

> Tom Bombadil is not an important person – to the narrative. I suppose he has some importance as a 'comment'. I mean, I do not really write like that: he is just an invention (who first appeared in the *Oxford  Magazine* about  1933),  and he  represents  something  that  I  feel  important,  though  I would not be prepared to analyze the feeling precisely. I would not, however, have left him in, if he did not have some kind of function. I might put it this way. The story is cast in terms of a good side, and a bad side, beauty against ruthless ugliness, tyranny against kingship, moderated freedom with consent against compulsion that has long lost any object save mere power, and so on; but both sides in some degree, conservative or destructive, want a measure of control. but if you have, as it were taken 'a vow of poverty', renounced control, and take your delight in things for themselves without reference  to  yourself,  watching,  observing,  and  to  some  extent  knowing,  then  the  question  of  the rights and wrongs of power and control might become utterly meaningless to you, and the means of power quite valueless. It is a natural pacifist view, which always arises in the mind when there is a war. But the view of Rivendell seems to be that it is an excellent thing to have represented, but that there  are  in  fact  things  with  which  it  cannot  cope;  and  upon  which  its  existence  nonetheless depends. Ultimately  only  the  victory  of  the  West  will  allow  Bombadil  to  continue,  or  even  to survive. Nothing would be left for him in the world of Sauron.

In Letter #20, Tolkien also reveals the out-of-universe inspiration for Bombadil:

> Do you think Tom Bombadil, the spirit of the (vanishing) Oxford and Berkshire countryside, could be made into the hero of a story? Or is he, as I suspect, fully enshrined in the enclosed verses?

<sub>**Note:** this answer is copied from [my answer to the same question on another site](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12111/17).</sub>